# HP presage of the PDA revolution

Tags: history

I no longer have clear memory of this, but I'm fairly certain I read an article back around 1979 or so published by Hewlett Packard. At the time, they had recently released their [41C calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-41C). I remember it being on my wish list, but unaffordable (I had the more affordable TI-58C). I believe the article was tied to promotional material for the 41C.

IIRC the article depicted someone going through a day with their "personal digital assistant". At the time, it was total fantasy - there was no public internet, no cellular network, the most powerful hand-held device would have been the HP-41C.

The "assistant", if I recall correctly, was depicted to have capabilities very close to what can now be done by an iPhone (given a cellular connection, internet access, and Siri).

I'd like to re-read the article to confirm what I think I recall of it. If anyone recognizes the article I'm referring to and has access to it, could they post it (or a reference to it)?

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but your question reminded me of this excerpt from Arthur C. Clarke's Imperial Earth I found in Byte Magazine Jan 1981 https://archive.org/details/byte-magazine-1981-01/page/n45

Comment: @rakslice I vaguely recall reading a story (I think by Clarke) which may have been Imperial Earth, but pretty sure the story I am seeking is not the one by Clarke, but thanks.